# How to do checks in REST?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have a collection of users. Each user have phone.

In application user can check if a user exists in application by sending a phone number.

How to do it in more restful way?

Answer (score 1):

```
GET /users?phoneNumber=1234
```

would return a collection of users that have the phone number `1234.

**Edit:**

Since you are not interested in the specific user but only in the fact that a user having the given phone number exists, the REST Resource would be this fact.

```
GET /user-phone-number-existence/1234
```

The name `user-phone-number-existence` is just a quick idea, you can change it, of course. The important point is that it is a noun, not a verb.

The response code would be [`204 No Content`](https://httpstatuses.com/204) if a user having the phone number exists. If no such user exists, a [`404 Not Found`](https://httpstatuses.com/404) would be the response code.

I see no necessity to include a body with the response, everything can be communicated using HTTP status codes.

Comment: well, is not a check, it's more a filter, we should not expose user date, only check if user with that phone is present

Comment: What user details would be contained in a user representation in a a collection? It is not necessary to include all details.

Comment: "GET /users" already return a collection of objects user{full_name, age, address, email, phone}, so "GET /users?phoneNumber=1234" should return the same, but this is not how it should be

Comment: How *should* it be?

Comment: {"phone": "223344", "is_present": true}

Comment: I have extended my answer.